# eclipse - Setting up C++ includes for GooglePlayServices

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am working on a cocos2d-x project and am integrating Google Play Services.

I am following the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/GettingStartedNativeClient

I am also referencing this guide:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid

I have set up my SDK and NDK and the Google play SDK location in the environment variables. The Google Play environemtn variable is NDK_MODULE_PATH="/Users/MyName/Documents/"

The gpg-cpp-sdk folder is in Documents too as the guide said I needed.

The guide mentions an example project 'minimalist' which I cannot find anywhere. I have moved passed that and done the step where it says to add in JNI_OnLoad:

```
gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration platform_configuration;
platform_configuration.SetActivity(state->activity->clazz);
```

When I compile, it complains that gpg is undefined. I went into my cocos2d-x project and added the header directory and the library directory and still no luck.

I've tried:

```
#include <gpg/gpg.h>
#include <gpg.h>
#include "gpg/gpg.h"
#include "gpg.h"
```

No luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of getting this set up? What should be included? Is my environment variable for the google play services set up correcty?

Thank you.

UPDATE: It seems that due to the fact I have a makefile, it's not even considering the include directories. The problem is that I have no idea how to tell the makefile or Eclipse to also include these directories.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ant and Makefiles.
If you have an Android.mk in the directory with the sources that use gpg, then add this to Android.mk

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
        $(HOME)/src/gpg-cpp-sdk/android/include
```

Adapt the path to your situation.
I keep the gpg sdk in ~/src/

And at the bottom of the Android.mk file:

```
$(call import-module,gpg-cpp-sdk/android)
```

Lastly, examples on how to use gpg-cpp-sdk, including Minimalist, live on hithub: 
https://github.com/playgameservices/cpp-android-basic-samples